# select query using apache camel sql component returns 1 row at a time

Tags: apache-camel

Am writing an sql route using spring dsl and making use of sql-component.
If my query returns 100 rows. Problem is my processor is getting called 100 times. Am polling my db every 60 sec.

So my from query acts like a producer of messages and keep sending one row at a time.

Is there any way i can get a complete result set of 100 rows in one go in my processor so that i can act on that data?

```
<from uri="sql:{{sql.selectQuery}}?delay=60s"/>
<process ref="sqlProcessor" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going through the documentation (http://camel.apache.org/sql-component.html) i figured out that

From Camel 2.11 onwards this component can create both consumer (e.g. from()) and producer endpoints (e.g. to()).

And i changed my route to

```
<from uri="timer://sqltimer?period=60s"/>
<to uri="sql:{{sql.selectQuery}}"/>
<process ref="sqlProcessor" />
```

This works fine. :)

Comment: You can also configure the consumer to not use the iterator, eg setting consumer.useIterator=false